# Free memory from vector of objects inside a function

Tags: c++, object, vector, memory-leaks, delete-operator

I have memory leaks inside my code but I couldn't figure out a solution to free the memory allocated inside the function where the object is created and pushed into a vector of an object.

The main function is the following:

```
void foo(vector<vector<BCC>> &features){

    vector<MinutiaPair*> matchingMtiae;

    for (int i = 0; i < features.size(); i++){

        Match(features[0], features[i], matchingMtiae);
        ms += s;

        // Free memory
        for (int j = 0; j < matchingMtiae.size(); j++)
            delete (matchingMtiae[j]);

        matchingMtiae.clear();

}
```

Each step of the loop a comparison is executed between values and a "new" vector matchingMtiae is returned with new objects. Then, for the next iteration, I want to completely free this vector and deallocate its content from memory. The Match function where objects are created and pushed into a vector `matchingMtiae` is presented below:

```
void Match(vector<BCC> &qt, vector<BCC> &tt, vector<MinutiaPair*> &reducedMatchingPairs) {

    vector<MinutiaPair*> localMatching;

    for (int i = 0; i < qt.size(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < tt.size(); j++)
        {
            double currSim = qt[i].Match(tt[j], true);  
            if (currSim > 0)
            {
                 qt[i].minutia.Flag = false;
                 tt[j].minutia.Flag = false;
                 MinutiaPair *pair = new MinutiaPair(qt[i].minutia, tt[j].minutia, currSim);
                 localMatching.push_back(pair);
            }


    sort(localMatching.begin(), localMatching.end(), MtiaPairComparer::ComparePointers);


    for (int k = 0; k < localMatching.size(); k++)
    {
        if (!localMatching[k]->QueryMtia->Flag || !localMatching[k]->TemplateMtia->Flag)
        {
            reducedMatchingPairs.push_back(localMatching[k]);
            localMatching[k]->QueryMtia->Flag = true;
            localMatching[k]->TemplateMtia->Flag = true;
        }
        else
        {
            delete (localMatching[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Debugging my code I realized that after the delete and clear of the vector `matchingMtiae`, the objects created were still allocated in memory and I can not understand the reason why this is happening since the pointer is not being lost but keeping it inside the vector.

I would like to deallocate the created objects from memory and completely clean the vector from pointers. Both are my aims.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be a 100% clear here: is your question about the vector keeping its pointers allocated or whether the pointers inside the vector still point to an object/memory address?

Comment: Get rid of pointers, new and delete for starters. None of those are needed here.

Comment: It's also rather unclear why you think you have memory leaks.

Comment: @Athosvk I am looking for both mentioned aims, I need my vector completely free to be fill again in the next iteration and free the previously created objects from memory to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @n.m. I run the Inspector tool from Intel and it warned me of it. Also I executed htop command from linux terminal and memory increase continuously over time.

Comment: Memory leaks are not evident in posted code. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: [Posted code has no leaks](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dccf82dca168362e). Any leaks are in the code you didn't post.

Comment: @n.m. sorry about that, I posted the complete code now, I thought the memory leak was happening because of the returned vector.. may be std::sort the cause of the memory leak warning?

Comment: FYI complete code is something others can run. Yours isn't. Please read on preparing a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "submit" a non-binding request to the C++ library std::vector to release its allocated memory by calling [`shrink_to_fit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) after `clear` or `resize`.

Note this is nonbinding which practically means every sane implementation actually releases memory but you cannot portably rely on this assumption strictly speaking.

I would also strongly suggest replacing the raw pointers in your vector with std::unique_ptr (or even just the objects themselves, if there is no concern of inheritance/slicing). It will ease the visual load of your function and prevent memory leaks in the future.

Comment: Note that the reason the memory is not deallocated is because of performance. Vectors often either have short lifetime where it'd already deallocate the memory in the vector's destructor or are reused (as we see here) where it's much more efficient to keep the memory allocated, rather than allocating/deallocating multiple times. The latter is quite wasteful, memory allocations and deallocations are not free, especially when you have a lot of them.

Comment: Instead of `shrik_to_fit`, you can also use good old `std::vector<MinutiaPair*>{}.swap(matchingMtiae);`. Note that the capacity of a default-constructed vector is not guaranteed to be 0, but it will very likely be in practice.

Comment: @DanielLangr right, in this case that's an option. It is not an option though if the vector is not empty.